# Why Page reload on SetInterval

Tags: javascript

```
    setInterval(UpdateGroupMessages, 10000,false);
function UpdateGroupMessages() {
    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        url: "GroupNew.aspx/UpdateGroupMessages",
                        data: "{'groupId' : " + groups[m].GroupId + ", 'name' : " + JSON.stringify(groups[m].GroupName) + ",'count' : " + JSON.stringify(count) + "}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var i = 0;
                            n = m + 2;
                            while (i < data.d.length) {
                                var str1 = "#tabs-" + n;
                                var str2 = " .messagesContainer";
                                var str = str1 + str2;
                                if (data.d[i].Image == "") {                                
                                    var UsernameAndMessage = BreakUsernameAndMessage(data.d[i].Message);
                                    ViewModel.addMessage(n, UsernameAndMessage[0], UsernameAndMessage[1], null, data.d[i].Video, data.d[i].PostedTime);
                                }
                                else {
                                    var UsernameAndMessage = BreakUsernameAndMessage(data.d[i].Message);
                                    ViewModel.addMessage(n, UsernameAndMessage[0], UsernameAndMessage[1], "ShareImages/" + data.d[i].Image, data.d[i].Video, data.d[i].PostedTime);                                
                                }
                                i++;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
                    });
                    m++;
                    k++;
                }
}
```

My Page reloads after data updation. Why does the page reload?

Comment: is there any error in the console ?

Comment: Nope, no error Just page reloads after the data gets updated

Comment: check this ```ViewModel.addMessage()```

Comment: No page redirect or reload in that function

Comment: Any buttons with type submit involved? Your code looks fine apart from being synchronous, you should really check the "external" calls like @Bonakid said.

Comment: Yep the submit button was the problem. Thanks buddy